# Is there a wy to expose S3 bucket over a web interface?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to allow my clients to upload files to my S3 bucket using a web based UI. I would like to authenticate them using a third part Identity provider and give them access to a screen where they can see a list of files and upload more files. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to **write your own web application to do this**. This will involve a backend that does the authentication, obtains the contents of the bucket and presents it to the user and gives them an interface for uploading.

When uploading a file to S3 via a web browser, the application should [generate an Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) that will allow the user to upload directly to the S3 bucket.